# Last 12months & next 4months with DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a date table with a date column. I would like to add a column which returns YES for dates that are in: **Last 12 months & next 4 months**

I need to build this column with a DAX formula and directly in Power BI desktop, so "not" in the power query with M language.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Is it  Last 12 months & next 4 months or  **Last 12 months OR next 4 months**

Comment: It is 12 months & next 4 months. Basically I need a period that starts from last 12 months till next 4 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you desired result

Note: Columns name vary as per your data.

```
YesOrNO = IF(DATEDIFF('Table'[Column1],TODAY(),MONTH)>=0,
If(DATEDIFF('Table'[Column1],TODAY(),MONTH)<=12;
"YES","NO"),
If(DATEDIFF('Table'[Column1],TODAY(),MONTH)>=-4;
"YES","NO"))
```

[image]

[image]